# Creating a formula to display "Y" if either one of 2 fields has a 'YES' in it

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have tried 2 formulas to get a "Y" on my report if one of two fields has a value of YES but I cannot get the formula to work.

Formula 1:
if ({Print.RetailRx} = "YES")
or ({Print.MailRx} = "YES")
then "Y"
Else ""

Formula 2:
if ({Print.RetailRx} = "YES") then "Y"
else if ({Print.MailRx} = "YES")
then "Y"

What happens is if retailRx has a value of "YES" I'll get the "Y" but it does not apply for MailRx.  Can anyone help?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In which scenarios is it failing? And what is it doing?

The first is probably the simplest solution:

```
if {Print.RetailRx} = "YES" or {Print.MailRx} = "YES" then 
 "Y" 
else 
 ""
```

You may just need to change the dropdown at the top of the formula editor to read: default values for nulls (instead of exception for nulls).

Comment: They both do the same thing. If I set print.RetailRx to be the first value to look for i will get the Y everytime the value equals YES but it won't work for the second field, Print.MailRx. For every yes value I get nothing. And if I swap them otu I get "Y" for all fields that apply but not for the second field in the formula. make sense?

Comment: Looks like the change in the formula editor fix the issue.  Thank you...  This forum is awsome

Comment: This is a good example of how null values can screw you up. If a field's value can ever be null then you should be checking `isnull` as the very FIRST thing you do in the formula and handling that odd case, otherwise they will crap out your whole formula. Even after years of using CR, stray nulls still get me.